# What is the purpose of a code block that isn't part of an if/function etc

Tags: php, statements

E.g.

```
<?php

echo "hello word";

$test = 1;

{

//sample php code inside code block

}

?>
```

Why is sample php code inside that code block. Is it purely to keep any variables defined inside it within the scope of the code block so no variables outside the code block get over written?

Comment: Variables will get overwritten in an anonymous block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most probably just for readability, since it doesn't create a new variable scope or something like this. Also as from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php):

> [...]Statements usually end with a semicolon. In addition, statements can be grouped into a **statement-group by encapsulating a group of statements with curly braces**. A statement-group is a statement by itself as well. The various statement types are described in this chapter.

Comment: To add to this, javascript this doesn't create a new variable scope either. But statement-groups do in C and Java. I'm not sure how it adds much to readability apart from being able to code-fold it in an editor.